# CentOS 6 fail2ban fails to ban http dos requests

Tags: centos6, fail2ban, centos6.5

Fail2ban fails to ban clients that make an excessive amount of requests over HTTP. SSH bans do work fine

To test this I have made several tests using `ab` and `curl` from other servers. I even made sure that i get banned over ssh. I did succeed, but I didn's succeed with the http requests.

```
ab -n 600 -c 10 http://domain.tld/
```

I have tried several regex rules for filters, which worked fine when tested a portion of the apache logs. I have the following result:

```
tail -n 10000 /var/log/httpd/<vhost>_access.log > /tmp/f2btest.log
fail2ban-regex /tmp/f2btest.log /etc/fail2ban/filter.d/cybertec-ban.conf
```

The result of this is as follows:

```
Running tests
=============

Use   failregex file : /etc/fail2ban/filter.d/custom-ban.conf
Use         log file : /tmp/f2btest.log


Results
=======

Failregex: 9583 total
|-  #) [# of hits] regular expression
|   1) [9583] ^<HOST> -.*\"(GET|POST).*
`-

Ignoreregex: 0 total

Date template hits:
|- [# of hits] date format
|  [10000] Day/MONTH/Year:Hour:Minute:Second
`-

Lines: 10000 lines, 0 ignored, 9583 matched, 417 missed
Missed line(s): too many to print.  Use --print-all-missed to print all 417 lines
```

I assume that the problem is not with the output. Please tell me if i'm wrong.

I put the rules into `jail.conf`, the rules look like this:

```
#
# Filter malicious http requests
#

[custom-ban]

enabled  = true
port     = http,https
filter   = custom-ban
action   = iptables[name=HTTP, port=http, protocol=tcp]
           iptables[name=HTTPS, port=https, protocol=tcp]
logpath  = /var/log/httpd/*access.log # <- this works according to the fail2ban log
           /var/log/httpd/access_log
maxretry = 500
findtime = 120
```

The `custom-ban` filter (which is located in /etc/fail2ban/filter.d/) looks like this:

```
[Definition]

failregex = ^<HOST> -.*\"(GET|POST).*
ignoreregex =
```

What am i making wrong? What did i forget?
How can i make these rules work?

Is there a name collision or something?

Answer (score 2):

You have `maxretry` set to `500` and `findtime` set to `120` so an IP address has to generate 500 relevant messages in 120 seconds to become banned.

I have no knowledge of your system, what it is being attacked by and how quickly or even what is normal. From the outside they seem a bit high, try reducing maxretry.